# When using Azure Key Vault or JWT what is the proper design for setting and retrieving/decrypting metadata. 1 to many or 1 to 1 keys?

Tags: node.js, azure, encryption, jwt, azure-keyvault

The use case is a user has a metadata that needs to be encrypted so when they sign-in a protected and stored object "encrypted" will be "checked" to verify the object information coming in plaintext is equal to what is in the encrypted object.

The question is, is it more appropriate in an Azure Key Vault to give each and every user a key with public and private key ability. Or, just use a single key that will encrypt the object that is stored and just un-sign/decrypt the object when it is accessed.

To me, the object is what is necessary to be encrypted and doesn't really relate to how the key is encrypted hence a universal 1 key to many approach.

The other approach makes sense too but I would have to create a hell of a lot of keys in order to facilitate such an approach. Is 1000's or millions of keys resulting in a key per each user appropriate?

What are the advantages or disadvantages of each other.

I think the same practice would apply to JWT token signing.

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to have one key and on a regular basis rotate the key.

For example, like they do in ASP.NET Core Data Protection API (I know you are using node) where they every 90 days (by default) replace the current key with a new one, and the old one is still kept to allow decryption of old data. In .NET they call this the key-ring, that hold many keys.

I did blog about this [here](https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en).

[image]

Also, do be aware that using some SDK's with Azure Key Vault, they try to download all secrets at start-up, one-by-one. That can be quite a time consuming if you have many secrets.

Comment: it's not many secrets it would be many keys. And the public key would be on the person's account. See what I mean? What do you think about that?

Comment: You also need to consider the cost for Azure Key Vault, as it might be expensive or "slow" if the traffic grows.  The question is if AKV is designed to hold 10000's of keys and if it is practical? hard to tell...

Comment: Yes, hard to tell. They say there is no limit but just rate limits. For example 2000 secret actions per 10 seconds. That seems like a lot.

Comment: I think it all depends on your use-case and I am sure you can cache keys in memory as well to offload key-vault.

Comment: If you wan to be GDPR compliant, then the ability to "delete" a key for a given user, would give you a easy way to make that data "anonymous" while keeping the objects around for "statistics"...

Comment: Perhaps it is this explanation with BYOK. I wish they would illustrate some examples. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/encryption-models#server-side-encryption-using-customer-managed-keys-in-azure-key-vault